# Haskell Error: "No instance for (Enum [Int])

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
betaRest :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
betaRest n prevDigits | n == 0    = (length prevDigits)
                      | otherwise = (sum (map (betaRest (n - 1)) [0..9]))

betaFirst :: Int -> Int
betaFirst n | n == 0    = 0
            | otherwise = (betaRest (n - 1) [1..9])
```

It gives me the following errors, and I don't know why.

> 1) No instance for (Enum [Int]) arising from the arithmetic sequence '0 .. 9'
>
> 2) No instance for (Num [Int]) arising from the literal '0'

Does Haskell think that things made with the ".." operator are enumerations? But why isn't there an error for the line that's 4 lines below (with "[1..9]") it then?

---

Edit: What I want the code to do is like this (procedurally):

```
int betaRest(int n, int[] prevDigits) {
  if (n == 0) return prevDigits.length;
  else {
    sum = 0;
    foreach prevDigit in prevDigits {
      sum += betaRest(n - 1, [0..9]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

int betaFirst(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  else return betaRest(n - 1, [1..9]);
}
```

Thus, betaFirst(1) == 9, and betaFirst(2) == 90. Yes, somebody may want to suggest a formula for generating this, but I'm going to add a filter of some sort to [0..9], thus reducing the range.

Comment: Not all errors appear in one run - some errors might not be displayed because the compiler is stopping due to other errors.  And yes, `..` *is* an enumeration, it's just you that doesn't think so.  Also, Why does `betaFirst` accept only one argument then get applied to two?  What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @thomas-m-dubuisson
Ah, so it is an enumeration. I suppose that there's a range function to use instead then.

Look closely, `betaFirst` doesn't call itself, it calls `betaRest`.

Comment: Try changing `[0..9]` to `[(0 :: Int)..9]`. It should give you a better error message.

Comment: The problem is probably in `betaRest`s otherwise branch.  There are some misplaced parentheses and one other problem having to do with list nesting.

Comment: @JohnL
Which brackets are misplaced? They all look fine to me; I put them around `betaRest (n - 1)` so I can use map with a function that takes multiple arguments.

Comment: `sum += betaRest(n - 1, [0..9]);` doesn't use `prevDigit`. Is it correct? If correct, then the loop can be replaced with `betaRest(n - 1, [0..9]) * length(prevDigits);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass `betaRest` to `map`. Map is `(a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]` so for `[Int]` list you pass it it wants an `Int -> Int` function. But partially applied `betaRest` is `[Int] -> Int`.

As for `[0..9]` its type is `(Enum t, Num t) => [t]` and it's translated into `enumFromTo 0 9` application. So compiler figured your error the other way around: if you define special `Num` and `Enum` instances for lists, so `[0..9]` becomes a list of lists of int, then your application will make sense.

But I think you want to use `inits` or `tails` function. Let us know what you want to achieve so we can help with solution.

A minimal fix to would be to add `prevDigits` as an argument to `map` and use a lambda abstraction to ignore unused `prevDigit`:

```
   | otherwise = sum (map (\prevDigit -> betaRest (n - 1) [0..9]) prevDigits)
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand why it's failing now, and why the error given is unhelpful/unrelated.

I'm a newbie, so I didn't know what either `inits` or `tails` is, but after looking them up, neither is what i want.

I've added what I want to do in the main question.

Answer (score 2):

```
(sum (map (betaRest (n - 1)) [0..9]))
```

Let's reduce the number of parentheses to better be able to see what happens.

```
sum (map (betaRest (n - 1)) [0..9])
```

The argument of `sum` is

```
map (betaRest (n-1)) [0 .. 9]
```

Now, `betaRest :: Int -> [Int] -> Int`, hence the type of the partially applied function is

```
betaRest (n-1) :: [Int] -> Int
```

hence we can infer the type

```
map (betaRest (n-1)) :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

But the argument passed to `map (betaRest (n-1))` is `[0 .. 9]`, which has type

```
[0 .. 9] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
```

The `Num` constraint comes from the use of an integer literal, and the `Enum` constraint from the use of the `enumFromTo` function (in its syntax-sugared form `[low .. high]`). Passing that as an argument to a function expecting an argument of type `[[Int]]` means the type variable `a` must be instantiated as `[Int]`, and then the constraints need to be checked, i.e. the instances of `[Int]` for `Num` and `Enum` must be looked up. Neither of these exist, hence the error messages.

I'm not sure your procedural example is really what you want,

```
int betaRest(int n, int[] prevDigits) {
  if (n == 0) return prevDigits.length;
  else {
    sum = 0;
    foreach prevDigit in prevDigits {
      sum += betaRest(n - 1, [0..9]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

the `foreach` loop is much easier (and more efficiently) expressed as

```
sum = prevDigits.length * betaRest(n-1, [0 .. 9]);
```

so for the `foreach` to make sense, there should be a dependence on `prevDigit` in the loop body.

The translation to Haskell would be

```
betaRest n prevDigits
    | n == 0    = length prevDigits
    | otherwise = length prevDigits * betaRest (n-1) [0 .. 9]
    -- or with the loop, with the small improvement that `betaRest (n-1) [0 .. 9]
    -- is only computed once (if the Haskell implementation is sensible)
    -- | otherwise = sum $ map (const $ betaRest (n-1) [0 .. 9]) prevDigits
```

But as stated above, I doubt that's really what you want.

Comment: No, it's not what I want, but because the function is confusing, I'm having trouble even making it out procedurally. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: Can you describe on a higher level what you want the function to do?