# No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of 'rem'

Tags: haskell

[Haskell "No instance for" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943114/haskell-no-instance-for-error)

[Haskell Error: "No instance for (Enum [Int])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685229/haskell-error-no-instance-for-enum-int)

[Function definition problems (No instance for … arising from)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713630/function-definition-problems-no-instance-for-arising-from)

[No instance for Num String arising from the literal `1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928166/no-instance-for-num-string-arising-from-the-literal-1)

**I am very new to Haskell**, and functional programming in general. In addition, **I am aware that the questions above are very similar**, but I have not been able to find a solution for my problem anywhere. The following code is meant to find the factors of a number input:

```
fc4 :: Double -> IO ()
check :: Double -> Double -> IO ()
fc4 a = check a (sqrt a)
check a b = if rem a b == 0 then print (b, div a b) else print () >> if b > 1 then check a (b-1) else putStrLn ("Done.")
```

I have attempted switching from `Double` to `Integer` and back with every possible combination, but every one fails with the same error:

```
No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of 'rem'
```

I have also tried explicitly using `fromIntegral` and `toInteger` on the arguments of `rem`, but no combination I have attempted has avoided this problem. I also see by the documentation that the type for `rem` is `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, and so it seems that using the same type for `a` and `b` would always work, whether it be `Double` or `Integer`.

Am I on to something? Have I made some terrible rookie mistakes? For reference, [here](https://github.com/StardustGogeta/Math-Programming/blob/master/C%2B%2B/Factor%20Calculator%204.cpp) is a C++ version of what I hope to achieve. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply replace `Double` with `Integer` in the type signatures, since you need to use a value whose type is an instance of the `Integral` type class, which defines `div` and `rem`. However, `sqrt` only returns values that are instances of the `Floating` type class, and there aren't any types that are instances of both.

The simple solution is to use `ceiling` to get an integral value that is just slightly larger than `sqrt n`, which will not affect the correctness of your algorithm.

```
 check :: Integer -> Integer -> IO ()
 check a b = ... -- same as before

 fc4 :: Integer -> IO ()
 --fc4 a = check a (ceiling (sqrt a))  -- because I didn't bother testing
 fc4 a = check a (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral a)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly, but I needed to use `fromIntegral` inside the `sqrt`.

Comment: Thanks again! This is even better than expected! With your improvement, I can even remove the type signature declarations entirely. However, I realized that I needed to change `ceiling` to `floor` to avoid repetition of (2,3) when finding factors of 6.

Comment: @StardustGogeta, it's generally considered good Haskell style to use type signatures for *all* top-level bindings. And it's often helpful to use them for local bindings too. There are some relatively unusual situations where type signatures can extend to several lines and be totally unreadable, but you're nowhere near there. Even then, the recently-added `PartialTypeSignatures` extension can allow you to write a signature without all the messy details.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you very much for letting me know about this!

Comment: To add to @dfeuer 's comment, lack of type signatures makes error messages even more incomprehensible because all the compiler can really say is that something in your code is inconsistent with something else, and it will usually guess wrong about which of the inconsistent lines is actually the error.

Comment: How can I use `fromIntegral` applied to 2 arguments, for example to `rem` or `mod`?